# How to clear Push Notification in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to cancel/clear a Push Notification in iOS?
(I know that [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] returns a dictionary and not a Notification object.)

Is there something similar for APN like for local notifications by calling:

1. `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];` for clearing one notification.
2. `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` for all local notification.
   ??

Earlier(in prev version of app) the APNs were getting cleared on clicking on them.
But, now they are not getting cleared. I just can't understand why?

The Entitlements key looks like this in the "Distribution" provisioning profile:

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>74T2SKP33D.com.xyz.abc</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.default-data-protection</key>
    <string>NSFileProtectionComplete</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>74T2SKP33D.*</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

I am using an ad-hoc profile and distributing the app through testflight.

Comment: Are you talking about clearing them from the notification center or from the lock screen?

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

would do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the app's badge number to zero will remove all push notifications from the Notification Center as well as clear the icon badge.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use cancelAllNotifications. Look into

[UIApplication Class Reference : cancelAllLocalNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelAllLocalNotifications)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]; but its not working

Comment: he explicity states it is about remote notifications